# I have a script and I want it to tell me how many paramters it has

Tags: bash, parameters, parameter-passing

I need it to tell me how many parameters i have in the program but it's not working the way I want

```
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; 
then
  echo "Illegal number of parameters is"
  me=`basename $0`
  echo "File Name: $0"
  echo "First Parameter : $1"
fi
```

Comment: `echo $#` will tell you the number of parameters passed to the script.

Comment: Btw do you try to access the positional parameters from inside a function?

Answer (score 2):

When you `echo` the `$#` variable, it gives you the number of parameters passed to the script

#### Content of script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Number of parameters passed are $#"
```

```
$ chmod u+x script.sh
$ ./script.sh apple 1 2 ball 3
Number of parameters passed are 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`$#` contain all you want whether passed argument to script or number of positional parameters passed to the function.

```
  #!/bin/bash

    myfunc(){

      echo "The number of positional parameter : $#"
      echo "All parameters or arguments passed to the function: '$@'"
      echo
    }


    printf "No of parameters passed:$#\n" 

    myfunc test123
    myfunc 1 2 3 4 5
    myfunc "this" "is" "a" "test"
```

Like

```
$ ./sample.sh 1 2 3 4 5
No of parametere passed:5
The number of positional parameter : 1
All parameters or arguments passed to the function: 'test123'

The number of positional parameter : 5
All parameters or arguments passed to the function: '1 2 3 4 5'

The number of positional parameter : 4
All parameters or arguments passed to the function: 'this is a test'
```